# URL absolute path not working with Linq To Excel on server. c#

Tags: c#, excel, post, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-excel

I'm using Linq to Excel library for reading excel tables. Until now, it was working good locally, the method ExcelQueryFactory gets the route of the excel by this way:

```
var book = new ExcelQueryFactory(@"C:\data.xls");
```

Now, I would like to use it online on a Rest Api, the POST used for uploading the Excel to the web api is the following:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Upload")]
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFile() {

        List<string> savedFilePath = new List<string>();
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }
        string rootPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles");
        var provider = new MultipartFileStreamProvider(rootPath);
        var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).
            ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(t =>
            {
                if (t.IsCanceled || t.IsFaulted)
                {
                    Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, t.Exception);
                }
                foreach (MultipartFileData item in provider.FileData)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string name = item.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", "");
                        string newFileName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(name);
                        Debug.WriteLine(item.LocalFileName);
                        File.Move(item.LocalFileName, Path.Combine(rootPath, newFileName));

                        Uri baseuri = new Uri(Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery, string.Empty));
                        //RELATIVE PATH
                        string fileRelativePath = "~/UploadedFiles/" + newFileName;
                        //LeerExcel(fileRelativePath);
                        //ABSOLUTE PATH
                        Uri fileFullPath = new Uri(baseuri, VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(fileRelativePath));
                        savedFilePath.Add(fileFullPath.ToString());
                        //LeerExcel(savedFilePath[0]);

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string message = ex.Message;
                    }
                }

              //  string rutaFin = "~" + savedFilePath[0];
               // string rest = rutaFin.Replace("http://localhost:56618", "");
               // LeerExcel(rest);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, savedFilePath);

            });
        return task;
    }
```

So, by choosing the excel manually, neither the absolute path or relative path on the server work for the ExcelQueryFactory string route.

The routes get by this method are the following:
ABSOLUTE: 
   http://localhost:56618/UploadedFiles/9a27e785-e486-4807-8a80-7abb9b940d8b.xls

And the relative:

```
/UploadedFiles/9a27e785-e486-4807-8a80-7abb9b940d8b.xls
```

Is possible to use by the way I want to? During the server is online, the obtained absolute path is accesible, so if I access to that URL, the file is downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved:

As I said, I thought only this library worked locally, but it wasn't.

Since Microsoft has launched a new big update, many people have notice some problems when using Database engine, [“Unexpected error from external database driver (1). (Microsoft JET Database Engine)” after applying October security updates.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2017/10/18/unexpected-error-from-external-database-driver-1-microsoft-jet-database-engine-after-applying-october-security-updates/)

First, I created a Fake.txt file on /UploadedFiles, folder that is located on the project repository and I give it permission to be always copied, as follows:

[Fake.txt properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXHEm.png)

With this file, I´m achieving that UploadedFiles folder is copied every time I run the server.

Next step:

Due to Microsoft big update, the recomendation is to "*download and install the [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True), and then modify the DB connection strings in Microsoft Excel to use ACE as a provider. Example: Change Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 to Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0.*"

I only have downloaded and install that file, but during this day, 3 new windows updates were installed, so, I dont know if this 3 updates are related with the solution of this problem.
The updates are:
[Update 1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2553338/description-of-the-security-update-for-office-2010-october-10-2017)

[Update 2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4011055/descriptionofthesecurityupdateforoffice2010september12-2017)

[Update 3](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2553347/july-14-2015-update-for-office-2010-kb2553347)

After installing the 2010 database engine version file, I changed the excel extension from .xls to .xlsx and now all work.